# Different eigenvalues in R and SPSS

Tags: r, spss, eigenvalues, canonical-correlation

I'm trying to understand some canonical correlation outputs, and I found differences between eigenvalues results for R and SPSS. Some code:

```
#From cancor help
pop <- LifeCycleSavings[, 2:3]
oec <- LifeCycleSavings[, -(2:3)]
cancor(pop, oec)$cor
```

The output:

```
[1] 0.8247966 0.3652762
```

I thougth that canonical correlations were the square root of eigenvalues. Then, eigenvalues should be

```
cancor(pop, oec)$cor^2

 [1] 0.6802894 0.1334267
```

If I calculate eigenvalues "by hand", according to [Everitt & Hothorn book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441996494), p.97, I get the same results. But, for any reason, I found that in SPSS eigenvalues are

```
(cancor(pop, oec)$cor^2)/(1-(cancor(pop, oec)$cor^2))


[1] 2.1278292 0.1539704
```

What's the reason for that difference?

Comment: The SPSS calculation does not appear to be of actual eigenvalues.  Where does it come from actually and what does it claim to represent?

Comment: @whuber, these are "the eigenvalues of the product of the model matrix and the inverse of the error matrix", as is stated here [link]http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/output/canonical-correlation-analysis/. But I don't know why SPSS calculates those values and R does not.